# Is there any way to create alias/variable for memory-related value in Radare 2?

Tags: radare2, stack-variables, local-variables

I wonder if it is possible in r2 to make alias for the value that repeats itself many times.

For instance:

[image: Image with movzx eax, byte [rbp + rax - 0x1020 assembly fragment]

I want to have an alias for `rbp + rax - 0x1020` to be named as `cwd[i]`.
Can it be done?

I haven't found any similar question before, would be great if it was possible.